# Instagram API - How to check last page last record?

Tags: php, api, recursion, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on Instagram API first time and also using social media API first time so I have very basic knowledge of how to call and read data from API. So I have created one recursive function to call next page and read data. Now I am storing `Media ID, Comments Counts, Likes Counts` for each and every post data with next page in my `instagram` database table. Now I want to insert one another record to my `schedule` table when API reached to last page and inserted all records to `instagram` table. I am adding my code below and I will happy if someone guide me to make code more proper :)

### My Code Work:

```
public function User($next=null){

    global $TotalHashTagPosts; // Total hashtag post counts
    global $CommentsSum; // Sum of comments
    global $LikesSum; // Sum of likes

    $AccessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/481959735/media/recent/?access_token=".$AccessToken;

    if($url !== null) {
        $url .= '&max_tag_id=' . $next;
    }

    $Ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $Result = curl_exec($Ch);
    curl_close($Ch);
    $Result = json_decode($Result);

    if(isset($Result->data)){
        $Data = $Result->data;

        for($i=0; $i<count($Data); $i++){
            if(empty($Data)){
                continue;
            }

            $LikesSum = $Data[$i]->likes->count; // Get likes total per media
            $CommentsSum = $Data[$i]->comments->count; // Get comments total per media
            $InstagramId = $Data[$i]->user->id; // Get media instagrammer id
            $MediaId = $Data[$i]->id; // Get media id

            $data = array(
                'instagram_id' => $InstagramId,
                'media_id' => $MediaId,
                'comments_count' => $CommentsSum,
                'likes_count' => $LikesSum,
                'created_date' => date(DATE_YYYYMMDDHMS_24),
                'status' => '1'
            );
            $this->db->insert('instagrammer_table', $data);

            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
                echo "Insert successful";
            }else{
                echo "Failed to insert record";
            }
        }

        if(isset($Result->pagination->next_url) && !empty($Result->pagination->next_url)){
            $next = $Result->pagination->next_url;
            $this->User($next);
        }else{
            $NextUrl = "";
        }
    }
}
```